# Jquery - Adding fadeIn / fadeOut to a hover addclass function

Tags: jquery, hover, fadein, fadeout

Alrighty so here's my current jquery code which on hover of div "fbox" replaces a background by changing the class for the div "fbot"

```
    <script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
$(function() {
     $("#fbox").hover(function () {
        $("#fbot").addClass("fboto");
    },
    function () {
        $("#fbot").removeClass("fboto");
    });
});
});



</script>
```

Now what I want is to add fadeIn and fadeOut to the changing background however I'm not sure of the proper way to do it, I've tried some different arrangements of it and it worked just not in the direction or order I wanted it to..

My html for those div's:

```
<div id="fbox">
<div id="ftop"></div> <!-- top of fullbox -->



<!-- middle of fullbox -->
<div id="fmid">
<!-- content for the fullbox goes BELOW here -->


<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />


<!-- content for the fullbox goes ABOVE here -->
</div>
<!-- end middle of fullbox -->



<div id="fbot" class="fbot"></div> <!-- bottom of fullbox -->

</div>
```

My simple css for the background image to change.. :

```
.fboto {
  width: 934px;
  background:url(images/cb/fboto.png) no-repeat;
  height: 17px;
  margin:0
 }
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to fade between background-images; although if you were willing to have the images in your markup and styled to approximate background-images you could use `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI allows you to animate adding and removal of classes. Simply by including jQuery UI's plugin you can do:

```
$("#fbot").addClass("fboto",duration,callBack);
$("#fbot").removeClass("fboto",duration,callBack);
```

For further reference : [jQuery UI addClass](http://jqueryui.com/demos/addClass/)

Comment: that's what I would do too, one class has one background image and other one another, and you can fade between them